# BeginGetResponse in Background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a Main page which gets news and n background loads from web other info:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(GetContacts);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

private void GetContacts(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(getServiceContactData);
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        long cont = 0;

       //This made to pause a thread for a long time

        do
        {
            cont++;
        }
        while (cont != 999999999);
        getServiceContactData();
}

private void getServiceContactData()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(GS.BACKEND_HOST + "sfbsfb");
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(HandleResponseContacts), request);
    }

private void HandleResponseContacts(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string JSON = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    if (JSON == "")
                    {
                        NoItems = true;
                    }
                    IsolatedStorage IS = new IsolatedStorage();
                    IS.Save("ContactsStorage.txt", JSON);
                    IS.SaveContactsRetrieveDate(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("got");
                    });
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

On the Contacts page there is:

```
string contactsRetriveDate = "";
        DateTime a;
        string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        string then = "";
        do
        {
            contactsRetriveDate = IS.ReadContactsRetriveDate();
            if (contactsRetriveDate != "")
            {
                a = DateTime.ParseExact(contactsRetriveDate, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                a.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            }
        }
        while(then!=now);
        MessageBox.Show("Estj");
```

This code checks the last update date of Contacts, and when now = then it shows message box.

The aim:

The aim was to downlad contacts data in background, so that there wasn't so much time to wait on the contacts page... In other words to start getting contacts data before the contacts page is opened.

**But code doesn't do HandleResponseContacts, it just doesn't enter that function when i navigate to the other page.**

Comment: You don't need to use background worker for periodic downloads, you can use timer which will trigger the download. `BeginGetResponse` is already on another thread and you are now basically wasting a whole thread for nothing. This spends CPU time and wastes battery a little more than needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found where i was wrong.

The wrong method was to get main thread on contacts page busy:

I should have done this:

```
string contactsRetriveDate = "";
    DateTime a;
    string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    string then = "";
    do
    {
        contactsRetriveDate = IS.ReadContactsRetriveDate();
        if (contactsRetriveDate != "")
        {
            a = DateTime.ParseExact(contactsRetriveDate, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            a.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
    }
    while(then!=now);
    MessageBox.Show("Estj");
```

In a background worker.

The code didn't work because the main thread was busy.